# SQL Query won't execute. Can't perform aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've seen other posts with this issue, but it is not clear as to how to solve the issue.

I believe the last update statement is the problem.  I'm trying to update a RatingValue which is the sum of ratings divided by the number of ratings.

```
DELETE
FROM EasyDNNNewsComments
WHERE CommentID = 168

DELETE
FROM ArticleRating
WHERE ArticleID = 6605 AND UserID = 10

UPDATE EasyDNNNews 
SET NumberOfComments = (NumberOfComments - 1)
WHERE ArticleID = 6605 

UPDATE EasyDNNNews 
SET RatingValue = SUM((SELECT RatingValue 
                       FROM ArticleRating 
                       WHERE ArticleID = 6605)) / 
                     (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                      FROM ArticleRating 
                      WHERE ArticleID = 6605)
```

Comment: so, what is the problem / error / issue here?? ANd could you provide some sample data please?

Comment: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use multiple queries for this. Simply use the aggregates as your math values.

```
UPDATE EasyDNNNews 
    SET RatingValue = (SELECT SUM(RatingValue) / COUNT(*) FROM ArticleRating WHERE ArticleID = 6605)
where ArticleID = 6605
```

Comment: Sean, can you edit your update statement to only update WHERE ArticleID is 6605.  It currently updates all records in the table.  The value is perfect though.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE EasyDNNNews 
    SET RatingValue = (SELECT SUM(RatingValue)/COUNT(*) FROM ArticleRating WHERE ArticleID = 6605)
    WHERE ArticleID = 6605;
```